# Unity: A Proper way to inject caller username on the server side of IIS hosted WCF service

Tags: .net, wcf, iis, unity-container

I am using custom `ServiceHost` to inject my dependencies on server side of WCF service as described in in [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn178463(v=pandp.30).aspx#sec31](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn178463%28v=pandp.30%29.aspx#sec31). Container is created and types are register in `UnityServiceHostFactory` constructor as described in the article.

**Question #1:** This probably mean, that there is a single instance of the container in my application (because there is probably single instance of `UnityServiceHostFactory`). Right?

My implementation  classes (not just the WCF service implementation class, but also the classes that are created by it) need the implementation `IAuhtenticatedUser` interface, that implements the method `GetCallerUsername`. Since there is a single instance of unity container in my application, I can not use `container.RegisterInstance` in `UnityInstanceProvider.GetInstance` to provide the identity at each call.

**Question: #2:** What is the best ways to provide the implementation of `IAuthenticatedUser` interface to my WCF service classes.

I am aware of two options:

1. Create child container ath the begining of each call and register a statefull instance of `IAuthenticateduser` in the child container.  The problem with this solution is, that I have read several articles, that creating/disposing  child containers is not thread safe (because they are being registered in parent container)
2. Implement stateless `IAuthenticatedUser` in such a way, that it would call `ServiceSecurityContext.Current` every time it is asked for username.

I am looking for a solution that would also work in scenario, when I am running async tasks on other threads as part of my server side call processing.  I remember reading that `ServiceSecurityContext.Current` might not get propagated to other threads in some scenario.

I also can not use PropertyOverrides, because this only works for the first level of Resolves, but not later, when in some scenarios my implementation classes  Lazy-ly construct other classes.

I am using .NET 4.51.

Any suggestions?

Matra

Comment: Have you taken a look at scoping in WCF with Unity? http://unitywcf.codeplex.com/

Comment: Yes, I did (includeing the original blog at http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/introducing-unity.wcf-providing-easy-ioc-integration-for-your-wcf-services), but it does not answer my questions. It uses child containers (see point 1. under my Question #2), and it probably sufers from thread safety problem. Foe example see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19687750/is-createchildcontainer-thread-safe

Answer (score 0):

Could you design your Services so the constructor relies on a interface. The IAuthenticatedUser should be be resolved when you register the container.

```
public class AccountService : IAccountService
{
    protected IAuthenticatedUser _user;

    public AccountService(IAuthenticatedUser user)
    {
        _user = user;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Injecting via constructor parameter vs. injectiong via [Dependency] does not make a difference. Both cases are resolved in similar way. My question is how (or wheteher do) I need to resolve to a different instance on each HTTP request - each HTTP request could be made by a different authenticated user.

Comment: Sorry, I assumed your service persisted for a specific session. In your case it would not work. For what its worth, I would look into a global ticket scheme that could be set by the incoming request, a cookie, and also used outside of a incoming http request that would work in other areas? Sorry about the mix up.

Comment: No problem. I already know how to extract username from incoming request by using `ServiceSecurityContext.Current`. The question is how to inject this to child objects in a proper way.

Comment: I had to do something similar in a wcf service using shared code. However,my context switching was done at a much higher level. All dependencies would be set up to a specific system. The system was a database and service discovery process for the system. Think of it as logging in against System1,System2,System3 being identical except for the data. When a user switched systems during login I had to create a top level function outside of the DI that would re-register all services using the selected "system". This would be similar to your situation,however,you switching would be more active.

Comment: Did you st up a seperate container on each request? In which pahse of WCF pipeline processing did you set up the container?

Comment: The DI Services were created in a BaseService class constructor, which would be per request if you are not using session. My case was unique in that once a connection was made to the Service(s) it remained until session timed out. Basically anti-SOA, however, it was the most efficient solution in my case.

Answer (score 0):

After much research, here is the answer:

1. Child cottainers  are the way to go. They are threadsafe. See also https://unity.codeplex.com/discussions/546984#post1251770
2. The "offical" Patterns & Practices implemetation is lacking fucntionality, that disposes created object. Without it, the child containers are not disposed and removed from parent container, and you have memory leak. Take a look at the following link to find outhow to solve this problem:
   http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/introducing-unity.wcf-providing-easy-ioc-integration-for-your-wcf-services